# Unable to reference an existing storage account when creating Azure Function app

Tags: azure-functions

I can't wrap my head around as to how link an existing Storage Account while creating a Function App in Azure. According to [Storage account requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli#storage-account-requirements), I must create or link to a general-purpose Azure Storage account that supports Blob, Queue, and Table storage. But that seams to be the case for my Storage Account:

[image: Existing Storage Account]

But I can't reference the pre-created Storage Account, it keeps prompting me to create a new one:

[image]

What am I missing ?

**EDIT:**
Just let the process create the Storage Account and apparently it is marked differently than the one I've created:
[image: created Storage Account]

I'll give it a go tomorrow morning, but if that's the case why it was failing, MS should really do a better job at documenting their stuff...

Comment: My (wild) guess, is that there are issues again with Azure.  This happened last week as well, read more here: https://status.azure.com/en-us/status/history/

Comment: Just update the question. Might be the issue with the version ?

Comment: Its things like this where I'm glad I'm sitting next to the equipment I am using.

Comment: One thing I have notified is Pre created Storage account should exists in same region where the function app is creating. What I tried is Created 2 General Purpose v1 storage accounts - one each in [Central US](https://i.imgur.com/Wkx9mgr.png), [Central India](https://i.imgur.com/6dwFtqu.png). In the Function App, if you select Central Us location then it will show the existing storage accounts in central US only and if you select Central India, you'll get existing storage accounts list available in central India.

Comment: Could you please check if the storage account exists in the location where your function app is creating?

Comment: @HariKrishna yep, that was the case, setting the correct region allowed me to select an existing Storage Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I have notified is Pre created Storage account should exists in same region where the function app is creating.

What I tried is Created 2 General Purpose v1 storage accounts - one each in [Central US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZmyO.png), [Central India](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF9IE.png).

In the Function App, if you select Central Us location then it will show the existing storage accounts in central US only and if you select Central India, you'll get existing storage accounts list available in central India.

[image]